# Why normalized feature weights for linear regression are bad feature importance predictors

Tags: linear-model, feature-selection, interpretation

I am trying to interpret a linear regression model. I assumed using absolute value of feature weight coefficients as indicators of influence of input variable onto output variable. However, it seems that features with the highest coefficients (they were also found strongly significant (Pr(>|t|)~5e-9 ) play minor role in the model compared to the ones with lesser coefficients and found significant at the level <1e-50).

What would be the correct way to estimate feature importance to be able to interpret the output variable? Should I order them by the absolute value of t-value or should I first filter them using the t-value and them sort according to the absolute weight? Any links on tutorials are also well appreciated.

Thanks